# The Info.plist Indicates a Mac app, but submitting an IPA

Tags: xcode, macos, mac-app-store, application-loader

I am attempting to submit a macOS app, but I am getting an error whenever I attempt to upload the package to the App Store. I have tried using both Xcode (8.3.1 (8E1000a)) and the version of Application Loader bundled with it. Both produce the same status.

If anyone knows of a possible workaround – I just need to submit this Mac app. Thank you.

Comment: Mac doesn't use `.ipa`, as that is meant for `iOS`.

Comment: I understand that macOS does not use IPA, that wad the problem. I was finally able to upload the package by using Application Loader 3 (an old version) which I found via an iTunes Connect link.

Comment: I had to download a previous version too and it worked. Are you using electron by any chance?

Comment: In my case I had `TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY` set in the build settings. Remove/override with empty string to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I fought a lot with that bug.

Xcode 9.2 I downloaded the .pkg created by Xcode (Export "App Store"). Then I tried to submit it using Application Loader v3.0 and got that strange error message: ERROR ITMS-90268: "The 'Bundle OS Type Code' [CFBundlePackageType] in your application bundle's Info.plist file must be 'APPL’." When analyzing the Info.plist file of the bundle from the .pkg, I found that Xcode changed the CFBundlePackageType string from APPL (as specified in the Xcode project) into BNDL. Note that, if I use Export "Developer ID" the string is "APPL" as expected. For me this is clearly a BUG in Xcode.

I solved that problem by 1- manually correcting the Info.plist file 2- manually re-signing the bundle with the codesign command 3- manually re-creating the .pkg with the productbuild command 4- manually signing the .pkg with the productsign commnand 5- submitting the corrected .pkg file with Application Loader

Of course the Xcode stage was not necessary but I wanted to understand the problem. The manual procedure is enough: codesign + productbuild + productsign + Application Loader

Answer (score -1):

Using Application Loader 3.0 worked for me.

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_3.0.dmg

Or you can try adding this code to your info.plist.  From Unity site:

If you’re using Xcode 8.0+, you also need to add these fields to the info.plist file:

```
<key>CFBundleSupportedPlatforms</key>

    <array>

        <string>MacOSX</string>

    </array>
```

This enabled using later versions of Application Loader